# transforming logistic regression

Tags: fractions, logistic-regression

I know that the logit function in logistic regression can be written two different ways:

$p = \frac{e^z}{1 + e^z}$

$p = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}}$

I'm weak on basic algebra and can't recall the steps in transforming the first equation into the second. Could someone walk me through the principles involved?

---

EDIT: Working out the solution provided by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner below:

$p = \frac{e^z}{1 + e^z} \cdot \frac{e^{-z}}{e^{-z}}$

Since $e^{-z} = \frac{1}{e^z}$ and $e^z \cdot \frac{1}{e^z} = \frac{e^z}{e^z} = 1$, therefore:

$p = \frac{1}{e^{-z}(1 + e^z)}$

Multiply out the denominator:

$p = \frac{1}{e^{-z} + 1} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $$e^{-z}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll work out the solution in an edit above.